# Share object between wcf service and mvc controller on the same website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

In my application, in need to use on singleton object,between wcf service and mvcController, the situation is :

- user login to my website and accept a special key which is valid for 10 minutes

  - he enters this key to another application
  - The application is sending a request to my wcf service, includes the key inside
  - My wcf service checks the key  for the user.
    I need a memory place to store the keys for 10 minutes

Wcf service and MVCcontroller hosted in the **same** webSite in IIS

I am not looking for solutions like database ,files or any IO suggestions, I need to use OnMemory.

I tried:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

Inaccessible from MVCController

```
 HttpRuntime.Cache
```

It sad, but this object's hashcode is different in MVCcontroller and WcfService

```
  MemoryCache
```

Same as above

Finally, I decided to declare my on cache using static object in a singleton pattern, however, while the static member initialized in the MVCContoller 
it still null in the WCFService

Does anyone can explain me what is going on? Does asp.net have different sections in memory for wcfService and MVCControllers?

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why no database? Storing cached stuff inside IIS memory is generally not a good idea (application pool recycling...etc.)

Comment: @ken2k, You right ,and there are so many options to achieve the needed result, but, I want to understand what is going on..